# HTML - Javascript -> Function call doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, html, web, networking, ip

I want to test a way to get my own Public IP ( Just for fun ).
Now I found a few Solutions... I found an API and I got a key for the API. I didnt get any error messages but the code just doesnt execute and I dont get any result back.

Heres the code :

```js
function json(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
}

function call_now() {
  let apiKey = 'The API-KEY';
  json(`https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=${apiKey}`).then(data => {
    console.log(data.ip);
    console.log(data.city);
    console.log(data.country_code);
    // so many more properties
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="Your_IP">
  <input type="button" onclick="call_now()" value="Get_Your_IP">
</div>
```

I dont know what to do, im not very familiar with Javascript so maybe you guys can help me a bit out. Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Are you sure the API is returning a response?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a browser? It may be blocked by CORS, so you need to call the API from a server.

Comment: Thanks guys I just found the solution. Case closed